# How to remove Print area preview from Excel sheet after running Print-to-PDF VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA code to print two selected sheets(Funnel & Other reports) from an Excel sheet using an ActiveX button to run the code.
After I get the PDF, the view moves to the last printed sheet and both sheets have print preview lines on the excel sheet. These are Page markings and not the dotted line that we normally see in excel.

[image: Excel screenshot]

I have tried removing the dotted print grid lines but that does not work. I need these tabs to be visible even after printing them otherwise I could have used VBA to unhide-hide them while printing to PDF.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\COMPASS_REPORT\"

If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir (Path)
End If


PDF_FileName = Path & "POP_" & Format(Now, "yymmdd") & ".pdf"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Funnel", "Other reports")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
PDF_FileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

I expect to get the sheet back to normal after printing PDF. Also if there is a way to control what sheet should be displayed at the end of the VBA code, it would be great. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView `? You can activate the desired sheet at the end of the code to display it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It works.